# How to ignore a file when commits to a certain remote repository in git?

Tags: git

I have two remote repositories `public` and `private` on Git, and I have one local repository `local` on my own computer. From time to time, I need to merge my local repository with the most recent commits from both `public` and `private` like this:

```
$ git pull  # pull from the private repo
$ git pull public main  # pull from the public repo
$ git commit -a -m 'Merged public and private'
```

Then push back to the two remote ones.

```
$ git push # push to the private repo
$ git push public # push to the public repo
```

The problem is, there are some `.txt` files (not all txt) in my local repository that I want to push to the `private` repository but not to the `public` one. The way I am doing it is: first run `git push` to push to the `private` repo, then delete these files manually from my `local` repo. Next push to the `public` repo using `git push public`. Finally add them back to my `local` repository. Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: You can't really control what will be _pushed_. What will be pushed is what is included in the revisions that will be pushed. You can't ask to push revisions and remove some files from what is in the revisions. The way you can achieve that would be by rewriting history of the branches involved so that the files do not show up in a branch (that will be pushed to the public repo) but you keep them in another branch (that will be pushed to the private one).

Comment: @eftshift0 Creating a new branch does not solve my problem because I still need to to update the new branch by manually deleting these files.

Answer (score 1):

Use submodules: include the "private" files in submodules and add the submodule only to the private repository.

Each clone of a repository contains everything, there is no way to "prevent" something to be cloned.

As such, if you are pushing to what are essentially two mirrors of the same devspace, you'll have logically separate private from public.